# Как сгруппировать объекты по значению свойства

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов вида:

```
var data1 = [
    { month:"Jan", category:"Final", value: "141" },
    { month:"Jan", category:"Raw Material", value: "3 513" },
    { month:"Jan", category:"Raw material class B", value: "1 551" },
    { month:"Jan", category:"Scrap", value: "116" },
    { month:"Jan", category:"Trading", value: "59" },
    { month:"Jan", category:" ", value: " " },
    { month:"Feb", category:"Final", value: "144" },
    { month:"Feb", category:"Raw Material", value: "3 631" },
    { month:"Feb", category:"Raw material class B", value: "1 591" },
    { month:"Feb", category:"Scrap", value: "116" },
    { month:"Feb", category:"Trading", value: "30" },
    { month:"Feb", category:" ", value: " " },
];
```

Каким образом его можно привести к виду:

```
{ category:"Final", value: [141, 144, ...] },
{ category:"Raw Material", value: [3513,3631, ... ] }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var data1 = [
{ month:"Jan", category:"Final", value: "141" },
{ month:"Jan", category:"Raw Material", value: "3 513" },
{ month:"Jan", category:"Raw material class B", value: "1 551" },
{ month:"Jan", category:"Scrap", value: "116" },
{ month:"Jan", category:"Trading", value: "59" },
{ month:"Jan", category:" ", value: " " },
{ month:"Feb", category:"Final", value: "144" },
{ month:"Feb", category:"Raw Material", value: "3 631" },
{ month:"Feb", category:"Raw material class B", value: "1 591" },
{ month:"Feb", category:"Scrap", value: "116" },
{ month:"Feb", category:"Trading", value: "30" },
{ month:"Feb", category:" ", value: " " },
];

console.log(data1.reduce((result, {category, value}) => {
  let target = result.find(row => row.category == category);
  if(!target) {
    target = {category, values: []};
    result.push(target);
  };
  target.values.push(value);
  return result;
}, []));
```